# Why facebook-android-sdk 4.5.1 missing from Maven repo?

Tags: android, facebook

Version 4.5.1 of the Facebook Android SDK was released in [13th, August 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads). Why is this SDK still not in Maven repository? The current available latest version there is [4.5.0](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.facebook.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22facebook-android-sdk%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x#4_5_1), it seems they also didn't put version 4.4.1 in the Maven repo either. Both of these updates only included changes to Facebook's **Audience Network** program, so my guess is that they didn't feel it was neccessary to update the repo.

Of course, if these changes affect you, you can still download the [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) from facebook